# Is there any way to use multiple fonts simultaneously in Vim?

Tags: vim, fonts, gvim, macvim

I'm looking to use Consolas and Helvetica (for example) within the same buffer.

Comment: In `vim`? `vim` is a command-line program; you can't decide from within the program what font the terminal uses to display text. If you meant a GUI version of `vim`, e.g. MacVim, that's a different thing, and [a different tag](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macvim). ;)

Comment: What would be the point? What kind of information would you want to show that is not already conveyed by color, weight or slant? I could understand the logic if you wanted to use a regular monospace font and a cursive, maybe (even if I think that would be utterly awful and counterproductive), but… two monospace fonts? They would too similar. Some explanations on what you want to achieve would be welcome.

Comment: @romainl Correct, I overlooked that the two fonts were monospace. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @romainl having multiple font sizes and shapes would make it a lot easier to read code - fx. think that you could make comments very small or in cursive or even bold, perhaps you could even have fonts so small that they could be used as pixels, enabling graphics to enter in comments or as dynamic content of log file -- I could go on with what this could be used for

Answer (score 4):

Well, sort of, in the GUI, if you're willing to use the syntax highlighting engine to do it.  See:

```
:help syntax.txt
:help :highlight
:help highlight-font
```

But be aware of this caveat in the documentation:

> All fonts used, except for Menu and Tooltip, should be of the same
>   character size as the default font!  Otherwise redrawing problems will
>   occur.

Comment: What are some of the worse redrawing issues (if you're familiar with them)?

Comment: Also, any link to an implementation would be great.

Comment: It's not something I've done, so I can't help you with either question. It would help if we knew why you wanted to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to fast change to a smaller font then use :
`ctrl -` to minimize and `ctrl +` to increase size

However I do not think pt. it is possible to have multiple fonts, it would be a feature I also would like to have